# How to freeze 'get method' while debugging program

Tags: matlab, debugging, get

For example，Add a program breakpoint on the 21th line“notify(obj,'UpdateGraph');”  24th line “[x,y] = MFunEval.grid(obj.Lm);”
The program steps to the 21th line ，you check “obj.hFun” .
At this point, the program will start to execute the “get method” in 24th line, but this is not what I want, and it will cause many accidents. matlab will open many build in function files.  (start to execute the “get method”  ------This makes sense, but I don't want the ‘get method’ to be triggered repeatedly when the debug view variable)
I want the program to execute sequentially.
How to not trigger the get method when viewing the variable without changing the program code. Are there any debugging tips here?

```
classdef  MFunEval<handle  %函数计算类
    properties
        hFun       %函数句柄
    end
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        Lm = [];   %区间
    end
    properties (Dependent = true)
        Data     %保存网格化数据
    end
    events
        UpdateGraph   %更新图形
    end
    methods
        function obj = MFunEval(fcn_handle,limits)  %构造函数
            obj.hFun = fcn_handle;
            obj.Lm = limits;
        end
        function fofxy = set.hFun(obj,func)
            obj.hFun = func;
            notify(obj,'UpdateGraph');       %广播事件
        end
        function data = get.Data(obj)        %获取网格化数据
            [x,y] = MFunEval.grid(obj.Lm);
            matrix = obj.hFun(x,y);
            data.X = x;
            data.Y = y;
            data.Matrix = matrix;
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        function [x,y] = grid(lim)       %网格化
            inc = (lim(2)-lim(1))/20;
            [x,y] = meshgrid(lim(1):inc:lim(2));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is, could you clarify further? “At this point, the program will start to execute” but only after you press the “continue” button. “I want the program to execute sequentially.” Each function is executed sequentially, but the various methods in your class will be executed only when they’re called, you cannot execute them sequentially. The `get.Data` method will be executed every time you read the `Data` field. Use the “step into” button in the debugger to see the order in which stuff is executed.

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for a way to mock the get method so it’s replaced by your mock function when debugging a different part of your code? See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mocking-framework.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo  but only after you press the “continue” button. “----No,the program will start to execute the “get method” in 24th line even you don‘t press the 'continue” button'